# Select matrix rows that are permutations of a given vector

Tags: r, matrix, subset, permutation

I have a matrix `X`:

```
     one two three four
 [1,]  1   3   2   4
 [2,]  2   0   1   5
 [3,]  3   2   1   4
 [4,]  4   9   11  19
 [5,]  4   3   2   1
```

I want to get a new matrix `Y` which only contains rows that are permutations of "1", "2", "3", "4". That is:

```
     one two three four
 [1,]  1   3   2   4
 [3,]  3   2   1   4
 [5,]  4   3   2   1
```

What function or command should I use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can try this

```
> mat[colSums(mapply(`%in%`, list(1:4), asplit(mat, 1))) == ncol(mat), ]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    3    2    4
[2,]    3    2    1    4
[3,]    4    3    2    1
```

Answer (score 9):

```
mat <- rbind(
    c(1, 3, 2, 4),
    c(2, 0, 1, 5),
    c(3, 2, 1, 4)
)

ok <- apply(mat, 1L, function(x) setequal(x, c(1, 2, 3, 4)))
mat[ok, ]
```

Answer (score 7):

Your example matrix and target vector:

```
X <- structure(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 0, 2, 9, 3, 2, 1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 5, 4, 19, 1),
               dim = 5:4)
v <- 1:4
```

But let's construct a more challenging one (thanks to user [harre](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4786466)):

```
X <- rbind(X, 1, c(1, 2, 1, 2))
```

**A fully vectorized approach (using package matrixStats)**

```
rk <- matrix(match(X, v, nomatch = 0L), nrow(X), ncol(X))
ct <- matrixStats::rowTabulates(rk, values = 1:length(v))
zo <- matrixStats::rowCounts(ct, value = 0L)

## all rows that are permutations of 'v'
X[zo == 0L, ]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    3    2    4
#[2,]    3    2    1    4
#[3,]    4    3    2    1

## remove rows that are permutations of 'v'
X[zo > 0L, ]
```

---

**Another fully vectorized method (base R)**

This is a mathematical solution. For a nonlinear and asymmetric weight function *w(x)*, the following weighted sum:

*1 x w(1) + 2 x w(2) + 3 x w(3) + 4 x w(4)*

is a unique score or identifier and is invariant to permutations. So for example, the following gives the same value:

*2 x w(2) + 1 x w(1) + 3 x w(3) + 4 x w(4)*

But anything else will give different values, like:

*1 x w(1) + 3 x w(1) + 3 x w(3) + 4 x w(4)*

*0 x w(0) + 3 x w(1) + 0 x w(0) + 4 x w(4)*

Here is an implementation using cosine weights. It works even if `X` and `v` are floating point numbers or characters.

```
## method = "tab" for tabulation method
## method = "cos" for cosine weights method
FindPerm <- function (X, v, method) {
  ## number of elements
  n <- length(v)
  if (ncol(X) != n) stop("inconformable 'X' and 'v'!")
  if (anyDuplicated(v)) stop("'v' should not contain duplicated values!")
  ## convert everything to integers 0, 1, 2, ..., n
  Xi <- matrix(match(X, v, nomatch = 0L), nrow(X), ncol(X))
  vi <- 1:n
  ## branches
  if (method == "tab") {
    ## row-wise tabulating
    rtab <- matrixStats::rowTabulates(Xi, values = vi)
    ## the i-th value is TRUE if X[i, ] is a permutation of v
    matrixStats::rowCounts(rtab, value = 0L) == 0L
  } else if (method == "cos") {
    ## evaluate cosine weights for Xi and vi
    w <- pi / (n + 1)
    cos.Xi <- cos(w * Xi)
    cos.vi <- cos(w * vi)
    ## weighted sum for Xi
    wtsum.Xi <- rowSums(Xi * cos.Xi)
    ## weighted sum for vi
    wtsum.vi <- sum(vi * cos.vi)
    ## the i-th value is TRUE if X[i, ] is a permutation of v
    wtsum.Xi == wtsum.vi
  } else {
    stop("unknown method!")
  }
}
```

```
X[FindPerm(X, v, "cos"), ]
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    1    3    2    4
#[2,]    3    2    1    4
#[3,]    4    3    2    1
```

---

**Benchmark**

Performance depends on the number of values in `v`. The tabulation method will slow down as `v` becomes long.

```
## a benchmark function, relying on package "microbenchmark"
## nr: number of matrix rows
## nc: number of elements in 'v'
bm <- function (nr, nc) {
  X <- matrix(sample.int(nc + 1L, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nr)
  v <- 1:nc
  microbenchmark::microbenchmark("tab" = FindPerm(X, v, "tab"),
                                 "cos" = FindPerm(X, v, "cos"),
                                 check = "identical")
}

bm(2e+4, 4)
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max
#  tab 4.302674 4.324236 4.536260 4.336955 4.359814 7.039699 
#  cos 4.846893 4.872361 5.163209 4.882942 4.901288 7.837580

bm(2e+4, 20)
#Unit: milliseconds
# expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max
#  tab 30.63438 30.70217 32.73508 30.77588 33.08046 135.64322
#  cos 21.16669 21.26161 22.28298 21.37563 23.60574  26.31775
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update** since there's so much interest in this question, here's a method using indexing to give a speed boost on Zheyuan Li's excellent generalization of my original answer.

The idea is to index on a `length(v)`-dimensional array for small `v`, or to index on `v*sin(w*v)` using the results of `match` instead of calculating `X*sin(W*X)` when `v` is large:

```
library(RcppAlgos)

# simplified version of Zheyuan Li's function
f1 <- function(X, v) {
  n <- length(v)
  Xi <- matrix(match(X, v, nomatch = 0L), nrow(X), ncol(X))
  vi <- 1:n
  w <- pi/(n + 1)
  rowSums(Xi*sin(Xi*w)) == sum(vi*sin(vi*w))
}

f2 <- function(X, v) {
  n <- length(v)
  
  if (n < 6) {
    # index an n-dimensional array
    m <- array(FALSE, rep(n + 1L, n))
    m[permuteGeneral(n)] <- TRUE
    X[] <- match(X, v, nomatch = length(v) + 1L)
    m[X]
  } else {
    nn <- 1:n
    u <- c(nn*sin(pi*nn/(n + 1L)), 0)
    X[] <- u[match(X, v, nomatch = n + 1L)]
    rowSums(X) == sum(u)
  }
}

set.seed(123)
# using Zheyuan Li's test dataset
nr <- 2000; nc <- 4
X <- matrix(sample.int(nc + 1L, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nr)
v <- 1:nc

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(X, v),
                               f2 = f2(X, v),
                               check = "identical")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr   min     lq    mean median     uq    max neval
#>    f1 344.4 367.25 438.932 374.05 386.75 5960.6   100
#>    f2  81.9  85.00 163.332  88.90  98.50 6924.4   100

# Zheyuan Li's larger test dataset
set.seed(123)
nr <- 2000; nc <- 20
X <- matrix(sample.int(nc + 1L, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nr)
v <- 1:nc

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(X, v),
                               f2 = f2(X, v),
                               check = "identical")
#> Unit: microseconds
#>  expr    min      lq     mean  median     uq    max neval
#>    f1 1569.2 1575.45 1653.510 1601.30 1683.6 3972.6   100
#>    f2  355.2  359.90  431.705  366.85  408.6 2253.8   100
```

---

Original answer edited to use `X + exp(1/X)` (see comments).

This should work with positive integers:

```
Y <- X[rowSums(X + exp(1/X)) == sum(1:4 + exp(1/(1:4))),]
```

Benchmarking against the `apply` solution:

```
f1 <- function(x) x[apply(x, 1L, function(x) setequal(x, 1:4)),]
f2 <- function(x) x[rowSums(x + exp(1/x)) == sum(1:4 + exp(1/(1:4))),]

X <- matrix(sample(10, 4e5, TRUE), 1e5)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1 = f1(X),
                               f2 = f2(X),
                               times = 10,
                               check = "equal")
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>  expr      min       lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
#>    f1 448.2680 450.8778 468.55179 461.62620 472.0022 542.0455    10
#>    f2  28.5362  28.6889  31.50941  29.44845  30.2693  50.4402    10
```

Answer (score 4):

This question is HOT. I am learning so I take this as a good opportunity to learn. It is really difficult for me to come up with new solutions, but I found two things missing here:

1. there is no serious validation of these answers;
2. there is no benchmark for all of them.

I would like to convert each answer to a function that returns a TRUE/FALSE vector for flagging rows. I also want this function to work with any matrix and any vector.

- [Stéphane Laurent's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73173842), [Zheyuan Li's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73173709) and [ThomasIsCoding's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73178986/19518065) need minimal adaption.
- [Mohamed Desouky's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73174380) is also easy to adapt, by taking out the function applied in `Filter()` and `apply()` it over matrix rows.
- [jblood94's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73177986) is challenging. It was commented that for other matrices and vectors, conversion is needed using `match`. I don't know what is the appropriate way, but I saw `match` in Zheyuan Li's answer, so I borrowed that part.
- [TarJae's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73173760) is awful (sorry; don't take this as an insult). None of them seems to work. I don't see any comparison between matrix rows and vectors in the base R solution. For other `tidyverse` codes, I don't know what `df_matrix` is. I have requested TarJae to please revise the answer.
- [harre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73176898) uses `tidyverse` and  dose not return TRUE/FALSE. So I have to exclude it from the benchmark (sorry).

Here are the functions for the benchmark.

```
S.Laurent <- function (X, v) apply(X, 1L, function(x) setequal(x, v))

Z.Li <- function (X, v, method) {
  ## number of elements
  n <- length(v)
  if (ncol(X) != n) stop("inconformable 'X' and 'v'!")
  if (anyDuplicated(v)) stop("'v' should not contain duplicated values!")
  ## convert everything to integers 0, 1, 2, ..., n
  Xi <- matrix(match(X, v, nomatch = 0L), nrow(X), ncol(X))
  vi <- 1:n
  ## branches
  if (method == "tab") {
    ## row-wise tabulating
    rtab <- matrixStats::rowTabulates(Xi, values = vi)
    ## the i-th value is TRUE if X[i, ] is a permutation of v
    matrixStats::rowCounts(rtab, value = 0L) == 0L
  } else if (method == "cos") {
    ## evaluate cosine weights for Xi and vi
    w <- pi / (n + 1)
    cos.Xi <- cos(w * Xi)
    cos.vi <- cos(w * vi)
    ## weighted sum for Xi
    wtsum.Xi <- rowSums(Xi * cos.Xi)
    ## weighted sum for vi
    wtsum.vi <- sum(vi * cos.vi)
    ## the i-th value is TRUE if X[i, ] is a permutation of v
    wtsum.Xi == wtsum.vi
  } else {
    stop("unknown method!")
  }
}

Thomas <- function (X, v) colSums(mapply(`%in%`, list(v), asplit(X, 1))) == ncol(X)

M.Desouky <- function (X, v) apply(X, 1, function (x) all((x %in% v) & length(unique(x)) == length(v)))

jblood94 <- function (X, v) {
  Xi <- matrix(match(X, v, nomatch = 0L), nrow(X), ncol(X))
  vi <- 1:length(v)
  rowSums(Xi + exp(1/Xi)) == sum(vi + exp(1/vi))
}
```

For benchmark, I followed the setup in Zheyuan Li's answer.

```
library(matrixStats)
library(microbenchmark); library(ggplot2)

nr <- 2000; nc <- 4
X <- matrix(sample.int(nc + 1L, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nr)
v <- 1:nc
microbenchmark("S.Laurent" = S.Laurent(X, v),
               "Z.Li.tab" = Z.Li(X, v, "tab"),
               "Z.Li.cos" = Z.Li(X, v, "cos"),
               "Thomas" = Thomas(X, v),
               "M.Desouky" = M.Desouky(X, v),
               "jblood94" = jblood94(X, v),
               check = "identical") -> bm1
autoplot(bm1)
```

[image: "bm1.png"]

```
nr <- 2000; nc <- 20
X <- matrix(sample.int(nc + 1L, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nr)
v <- 1:nc
microbenchmark("S.Laurent" = S.Laurent(X, v),
               "Z.Li.tab" = Z.Li(X, v, "tab"),
               "Z.Li.cos" = Z.Li(X, v, "cos"),
               "Thomas" = Thomas(X, v),
               "M.Desouky" = M.Desouky(X, v),
               "jblood94" = jblood94(X, v),
               check = "identical") -> bm2
autoplot(bm2)
```

[image: "bm2.png"]

I don't know how time is transformed for plotting, but clearly, they are not on the usual scale. Those to the left are far faster than it is suggested from the plot!

**Conclusion:** Zheyuan Li's "cos" method is the winner.

Answer (score 3):

**Another option is using `Filter` function**

```
t(Filter(\(x) all((x %in% 1:4) & length(unique(x)) == 4) ,
data.frame(t(X))))
```

**Just for fun**

Who can give me 4 distinct digits whose sum equal 6 ?

- there is just {0,1,2,3}

then we can use the module of 4 using `%%`

```
X[apply(X , 1 , \(x) sum(unique(x %% 4)) == 6 & length(unique(x)) == 4) , ]
```

**OR**

with Using pure `for loop`

```
ans <- data.frame(matrix(NA , ncol = ncol(X)))
r <- 1
for(i in 1:nrow(X)){
    if(all((X[i,] %in% 1:4) & length(unique(X[i,])) == 4)){
        ans[r,] <- X[i,]
        r <- r + 1
    }
}

ans <- as.matrix(ans)
```

- output

```
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1  3  2  4
2  3  2  1  4
3  4  3  2  1
```

- data

```
X <- matrix(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 0, 2, 9, 3, 2, 1, 1, 11, 2, 4, 
              5, 4, 19, 1) , ncol = 4)
```

Answer (score 2):

For the fun of `tidyverse`-solutions, even if I think we'd rather work on the matrices directly. However, we could use `rowwise()` and `c_across()`:

With set-operations (inspired by @Stéphane Laurent):

```r
library(dplyr)

mat %>% 
  as_tibble() |>
  rowwise() |>
    filter(setequal(c_across(), c(1, 2, 3, 4))) |>
  ungroup() |>
  as.matrix()
```

Or without set-operations:

```r
library(dplyr)

mat %>% 
  as_tibble() |>
  rowwise() |>
  filter(1 %in% c_across(everything()) &
         2 %in% c_across(everything()) &
         3 %in% c_across(everything()) &
         4 %in% c_across(everything())
         ) |>
  ungroup() |>
  as.matrix()
```

Or inspired by @Mohamed Desouky:

```r
mat %>% 
    as_tibble() |>
    rowwise() |>
      filter(all(c_across() %in% 1:4) & n_distinct(c_across()) == 4) |>
    ungroup() |>
    as.matrix()
```

And so on..

Answer (score 2):

The `algorithm` library in `C++` offers a function called `std::is_permutation` that does just the trick.

The workhorse function below uses `Rcpp` and is fairly straightforward.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>

// [[Rcpp::export]]
SEXP perm_idx_cpp(Rcpp::IntegerMatrix mat, const std::vector<int> &v) {
  
    const int nRows = mat.nrow();
    const int nCols = mat.ncol();
    
    std::vector<int> test(nCols);
    Rcpp::LogicalVector res(nRows);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < nRows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nCols; ++j) {
            test[j] = mat(i, j);
        }
        
        res[i] = std::is_permutation(
            test.begin(), test.end(), v.begin()
        );
    }
    
    return res;
}
```

And calling it in `R` we have (N.B. We use `match` to get integer indices as in @Zheyuan Li's answer, which is absolutely brilliant btw!):

```r
get_perm_idx <- function(X, v) {
    Xi <- matrix(match(X, v, nomatch = 0L), ncol = ncol(X))
    perm_idx_cpp(Xi, seq_along(v))
}
```

It is very efficient as well. Here is a simple benchmark:

```r
nr <- 2e4
nc <- 20
X <- matrix(sample.int(nc + 1L, nr * nc, replace = TRUE), nr)
v <- 1:nc
microbenchmark("tab" = FindPerm(X, v, "tab"),
               "cos" = FindPerm(X, v, "cos"),
               "is_perm_cpp" = get_perm_idx(X, v),
               check = "identical")
Unit: milliseconds
        expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq       max neval
         tab 33.641345 36.479660 39.00994 37.402306 39.560015  54.88057   100
         cos  9.496309 12.887493 15.30122 13.306302 14.053643 132.24079   100
 is_perm_cpp  3.232093  4.819553  6.08687  4.993367  5.248818  19.56919   100
```

You could probably squeeze out some extra efficiency, but it is tough to beat the simplicity here.